# Variable and Dynamic Pricing in Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a 3 part operation in gravity forms that I can't seem to figure out.

Step 1. User inputs numeric value. (ie 25)

Step 2. The numeric value of step 1 (ie 25) generates a price based on the range that it fell in (1-10 = $1 per value, 11-20 = $1.50 per value, 21-30 = $2.00 per value)(ie 25 = 25 x $2.00 = $50.00).

Step 3. Create a drop-down of options that all have multipliers based on original numeric value from step 1. (ie a = +$1.00 per value, b = +$1.50 per value, c = +$2.00 per value).

And I would be adding several options like step 3.

So all-in-all, I need the form to start with a value that the user inputs. And then I need a long list of options with prices all based on what was input in that original value. These prices would be calculated in 2 ways: either based on the numeric value falling within a range that dictates its price (step 2), or based strictly as a multiplier of the numeric value (step 3).

Answer (score 1):

Step 2 can be handled by [GP Conditional Pricing](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gp-conditional-pricing/). Step 3 will require a decent bit of PHP and JS coding to handle setting the price on the frontend and validating it on submission. Not something that can be easily provided in a set of instructions.

Comment: that plugin is way too expensive. Again it's not a one time purchase